# Get Active Directory Details In .NET Core App

Tags: .net, .net-core, active-directory

I have a .NET Core 2.0 web app running on an internal server through IIS. The server is only accessible if the user has logged on via Active Directory. Is there any way that I can easily retrieve the user's details as I want to use AD for managing the roles

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to find who the current user is and other properties, try this.

```
public static string currentUserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```